# spotify API query not producing Album metadata

Tags: api, spotify

I'm trying to build a app that  gets info from the Spotify API but since I don't have the Spotify ids I want to grab the ids using  search queries.

I wanted to just try it so I tested it with an album called yellow and a band called SCANDAL. However when I query, say, `https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=album:yellow+artist:scandal&type=album` it comes up with nothing. However when I Google the band, I got an artist id: `7hTZwqQILVH4bAbN67CeEz` from the URL.

using the get albums query(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/7hTZwqQILVH4bAbN67CeEz/albums?album_type=album&limit=5`) it shows that the album exists but the original query didn't find it. Am I doing something wrong or does it only work with more popular artists (I tried other albums and it was fine)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your query. I think you are hitting a bug.

Bug reports for Spotify Web API can be found in Github issues

According to this bug:

https://github.com/spotify/web-api/issues/194

setting no market parameter will make it default to US. Your query seems to confirm this bug. Since SCANDAL Yellow is not available in the US, you will not see it in the results. If you add market=SG for instance, it will show up.

Comment: Ah OK Thanks. I so say if I had no clue which markets it was a available in would I just add all the markets to the query or is there a smarter way?

Comment: No. market parameter only takes one market and you can't add the parameter more than once. You should do what you currently do, have no market set, and the response will include all albums which is available in any market and for each album you will see in available_markets where it is available. This is clearly a bug in the Spotify Web API.